# need help setting up https redirect

Tags: https, tomcat

I am an utter network newbie.

I have 1 Google Compute server. Let's say its ip is 111.222.33.4

Its running Apache Tomcat and serves up different pages on http and https

http://111.222.33.4/myPage and http://111.222.33.4:8080/myPage both serve up myPage properly

Following instructions I found online, I changed the https port (443) to 8443 and modified Tomcat server.conf to cause traffic on port 8443 to

I can access mySecurePage as follows:

https://111.222.33.4:8443/mySecurePage

But, I want to be able to type in:

https://111.222.33.4/mySecurePage

and have that work.

I haven't the faintest idea what to Google to figure this out.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why did you change the port 443 to 8443 in the first place if you want to use 443?

Comment: the instructions i followed to set up https support in Tomcat changed it to 8443.  i just want it to work and don't care about the specific port number.  is changing it back to 443 reasonable?

Comment: Well, 443 is the default port for https. If you don't run anything else on that server that should be accessible with https it would be the easiest solution.